# Getting element with htmlunit driver doesn't work

Tags: selenium, webdriver, htmlunit

I am trying to grab the location of an image from a website with Selenium. Here is my code:

```selenium
    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);        
    driver.get("http://mini.imbc.com/index.html?service=onair&channel=mfm");
    WebElement dynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 300)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='viewer bg-black30']/img")));
    System.out.println(dynamicElement.getAttribute("outerHTML"));        
    driver.quit();
```

But this code doesn't work which was fine with ChromeDriver. The following is what the `img` element actually is when I look at the page's DOM:

```html
<img width="298" height="168" src="http://img.imbc.com/adams/Program/20149/130555114063940358_Big_C.png">
```

How can I get the element?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the parent is a div element with the css classes *viewer* and *bg-black30* ?

You should use css selectors instead, that’s much easier.
In your case it would be

```
By.cssSelector("div.viewer.bg-black30 img")
```

Take a look at [the 30 css selectors you must memorize](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Comment: Thanks. However, the problem was htmlunit webdriver doesn't work which was fine with chrome driver. ChromeDriver(): O, HtmlUnitDriver(true): X

Comment: Maybe there is some JavaScript on the page that puts you're images in the DOM.
You have JavaScript enabled in HtmlUnitDriver, but if you are using a JavaScript-Framework it might not work with HTMLUnits JavasScript engine.